# sendSimpeMessage returning 500

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I believe i have some endpoint issue with my current controller.
I'am trying to send an email using JavaMailSender.

The example below works just fine when sending hardcoded string values.

```
    @RequestMapping("/sendhc")
    public void sendSimpleMessage() {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo("firstname.lastname@gmail.com");
        message.setSubject("subject");
        message.setText("text");
        emailSender.send(message);
    }
```

I want to be able to make a request with the values instead of the hardcoded string example as shown above. When posting this i get the NullPointerException.

```
    @RequestMapping("/send")
    public void sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        emailSender.send(message);
    }
```

[image]

I'm trying POST to `localhost:8080/send`, with the following values: (as shown in image above)

`{
    "to":"email@gmail.com",
    "Subject":"New Errand",
    "text":"loremloremloremloremlorem"
}`

Any suggestions of where I could've gone wrong are much appreciated.

Comment: You should use `@RequestBody` for sending data to your endpoint

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending the parameters as JSON in the body of the request, you need to specify that in the request, and then convert to Java, e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping("/send")
public void sendSimpleMessage(@RequestBody String json) {
   // convert json to Java DTO class using e.g. flexjson.JSONDeserialier
```

Alternately, instead of sending in the body, you could specify path variables:

```
@RequestMapping("/send/to/{to}/subject/{subject}/text/{text}")
public void sendSimpleMessage(@PathVariable("to") String to, @PathVariable("subject") String subject, @PathVariable("text") String text,) {
```